# Simple Calendar

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm using the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) and selected the date picker.

I'm wondering if anyone has created a simple calendar plugin that can grab the field and produce a calendar. How should I do that?

Comment: Pretty much every events plug-in will allow you to create a calendar. Is there a particular need for it be based on ACF? What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As @Vincius mentioned above, I don't think anyone has created a full-blown calendar with ACF and ACF alone. But - that doesn't mean you can't plug into other Event Calendars (or --> attach the ACF data onto their Events post type). For example:

[Sugar Event Calendar](http://pippinsplugins.com/sugar-event-calendar-wordpress/)

- It has a filter hooks (look on that page, under `Hooks`) that allow you to override each query generated by the plugin. That way, if you had another post type, you could override the default query from `post_type => 'events'` to `post_type => array('events','your_post_type')`
- If you setup your ACF fields and attach them to the Event post type, what you can then do is  [remove_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) on whatever  meta boxes you would like to hide (that would have date info) and then setup your ACF fields to map to the same meta_keys. This one is more dangerous though - as if the dev changes something with how the meta fields are saved, you could run into trouble.

But, if you use the second example and just add-on additional data you need, every decent event plugin will allow you to override the respective views for each area - and you can then use normal ACF functions to output your data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any plugin like this. Anyway, you should provide specific information of what kind of calendar you want. By general means, `strtotime` is your friend.

For example, to generate a day listing of the current month with a highlighted date from the custom field, you would do something like:

```
$date_field = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( get_field( 'date_field' ) ) );
$current_month = date( 'Y-m-' );
for ( $day = 1; $day < date( 't' ); $day++ ) {
    $day_of_month = $current_month . $day;
    if ( $day_of_month == $date_field )
        <span class="highlight"><?php echo $day_of_month; ?></span>
    else
        <span class="normal"><?php echo $day_of_month; ?></span>
}
```

Note: the above code is not tested.